# Identifying an unknown Android tablet through adb/shell without relying on build.prop

Tags: adb, root-access, hardware, tablet, shell

I obtained a cheap unbranded tablet from a friend, without a box or anything and I need to figure out what kind of tablet it is, through software.

What I've established so far is that the tablet is an Alwinner A13, but unfortunately there are a lot of A13s and this one seems to require some non-standard touchscreen drivers.

There are a few more threads about identifying devices, but this case is slightly different, in that I can't trust anything Android tells me about the tablet. 
The tablet is currently running the official Novo 7 Legend firmware, which "works" but unfortunately is not the right firmware for the device. I still have full access to the system over adb and with a mouse over OTG, however the device's build.prop is wrong. 
Unfortunately build.prop is also what defines the tablet's type/name in the Android "About device" section and all Android log output I've found.

I've checked dmesg as well as the output of `adb bugreport`, neither gave me what I'm looking for.

**tl;dr:** 
I do not have the original firmware nor do I have the box and the hardware is very generic, so my question is, is there any (software-wise) way of identifying the tablet, that does not rely on build.prop?

I have full (root) adb access and full access to Android.

**Update:** I have opened up the tablet and checked the board (and lost the power button in the process), on it was a more specific name, but still very generic. I did manage to get some rom working on it thanks to it (albeit with an inverted touchscreen), but I still haven't been able to identify it. I've given up on it for now (I got it for tinkering purposes anyway), if I get new suggestions here I'm still more than happy to try them out however.

Comment: I'm not sure how to determine where a system info app obtains its information (except the app desc says so, or you asked the dev). However, a list of possible candidates might be found here: [System-Info Tools](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=184). If you found the one you're looking for, feel encouraged to answer your own question, so others might benefit of your discovery :)

Comment: Wups, sorry, forgot about this question. I have used some of the apps on that page, but they all either read build.prop or only list the hardware (which I already knew), so unfortunately that didn't solve the problem

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried these:

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.device
adb shell getprop ro.product.model
adb shell getprop ro.product.name
```

EDIT: Upon re-reading the question, it seems that my suggestion is not applicable.
I trust that you have a stock recovery? If so, connect it to PC while in recovery mode and do the following over ADB:

```
adb shell
cat default.prop
```

If `default.prop` still does not give you what you want, I'm really sorry but I can't think of any other solution than to look for a stock firmware.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, unfortunately I got the device with a generic Allwinner A13 CWM installed, so that didn't help either. Thanks for the suggestion though.